# How to fix Bundle Identifier in Flutter Xcode Project?

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, bundle-identifier

I am trying to setup flutter xcode project with firebase, but I am not able to generate `GoogleService-Info.plist` as I am not able to get the bundle identifier id it is showing as in the image shared, how should I resovle it, bundle identifier is inactive [image: here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your flutter project ... ios > Runner.xcodeproj > project.pbxproj
Then search for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER and that will be it.

[image: file path for finding project bundle identifier]